# The length of POST request

Tags: java, post, request, netty

I'm working with Netty Http Server, but I found a problem.

In short words: when I sending something via POST AJAX request, Netty server catch only first 55 characters from a content of the request. This is my code:

```
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    if (msg instanceof HttpContent) {
        HttpContent httpContent = (HttpContent) msg;
        ByteBuf content = httpContent.content();
        if (content.isReadable()) {
            String message = content.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }
}
```

The initialize class is as follows:

```
public class HttpServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    private final SslContext sslCtx;

    public HttpServerInitializer(SslContext sslCtx) {
        this.sslCtx = sslCtx;
    }

    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
        ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
        if (sslCtx != null) {
            p.addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc()));
        }
        p.addLast("aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator(1048576));
        p.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());
        p.addLast(new HttpServerHandler());
    }
}
```

Comment: "Netty server catch only first 55 *charts*": Did you mean _chars_, as in characters?

Comment: Yes Krumia, characters :)

Comment: have you increased the standard HTTP message parameters that are default for the object/decoder? e.g. new HttpObjectAggregator(512 * 1024)

Comment: @paziwatts - I use HttpObjectAggregator. I edited my question and there is a code

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find the answer.
The initChannel() method should contains this code:

```
public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
    ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
    if (sslCtx != null) {
        p.addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc()));
    }
    p.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
    p.addLast("aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator(1048576));
    p.addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());
    p.addLast(new HttpServerHandler());
}
```